# Format navbar color and add dividers in Razor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am down to my last few things for my first project.  Now, I am trying to edit the navbar.  It currently looks like this:

[image: Current Navbar]

However, I want it to look like this (mostly):

[image]

The things that I want to copy are:

1. add in the | character after each selection
2. Change the Navbar color to that color
3. change the font color to white
4. Change the font style

Here is the code for my Navbar action links:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Ticket", "Create", "Ticket")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Open On Behalf", "ChooseOpenBehalf", "Ticket")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Search Tickets", "ChooseSearchView", "Ticket")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Open Ticket", "GetTicket", "Ticket")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Knowledgebase", "ChooseSearchView", "Knowledgebase")</li>
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("View Open Tickets", "Index", "Ticket")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("View Deffered Tickets", "DefferedTickets", "Ticket")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("View Closed Tickets", "ClosedTickets", "Ticket")</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
```

and here is the CSS that I tried for changing the navbar color:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ff6a00;
}
```

and here is the CSS that I tried for adding the borders:

```
.navbar-fixed-top li a{
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.navbar-fixed-top li:last-child a{ 
   border-right: none;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what don't you just use plain css adding border

```
#navigation li a{
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

#navigation li:last-child a{ 
   border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Put that in my site.css file? or in my layout file?

Also, how do I change the color, because I tried that.

Comment: your css file change #navigation for id of your menu

Comment: and border-color for changing color in your border

Comment: I made changes to my original post.  That is what I have and it is not working.  Also, when I said color, I meant the color for the background of the navbar and for the font.

Comment: sorry borders are working.  A simple refresh did not get them to work.  I had to restart my project.  How do I change the font color and the background color?

Comment: background-color: #000000; but i think your background color got ovveride try background-color: #000000 !important;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81325/discussion-between-darkvision-and-djblois).